# The leading zero is changing the result in php

Tags: php

Let us assume In PHP

```
$i = 016;
echo $i / 2;
```

The output is returning `7`.! why..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appending 0 to the front of a number in PHP is making it octal.

16 in octal is equivalent to 14 in decimal.

So , 14/2 = 7 is the answer.

Comment: This is why people make fun of PHP

Comment: It's like this in most of languages.

Comment: can you explain  this: `Appending 0 to the front of a number in PHP is making it octal.16 in octal is equivalent to 14 in decimal.` how..??????

Comment: In PHP , Integers can be specified in decimal (base 10), hexadecimal (base 16), octal (base 8) or binary (base 2) notation, optionally preceded by a sign (- or +).  To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero). To use hexadecimal notation precede the number with 0x. To use binary notation precede the number with 0b.

Answer (score 0):

The leading `0` will cause `016` to be interpreted as written in base `8`, thus in base `10` it will actually be `14`.
So `14/2 = 7`